# Why doesn't DBI's RaiseError always trigger my CORE::GLOBAL::die subroutine?

Tags: perl, dbi

I overrode `CORE::GLOBAL::die` as described in brian d foy's [article on the subject](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2011/05/override-die-with-end-or-coreglobaldie/):

```
BEGIN {
    *CORE::GLOBAL::die = sub {
        say "In CORE::GLOBAL::die: [@_]";
        CORE::die(@_) if $^S;
        exit 1;
    }
}
```

The ultimate goal is to write fatal errors to a log, but this is good enough for now. Let's create a database handle with `RaiseError` turned on and do something to trigger an error:

```
use DBI;

# Wrong password
my $dbh = DBI->connect(..., { PrintError => 0, RaiseError => 1 });
```

Outputs:

```
In CORE::GLOBAL::die: [DBI connect(...) failed: Access denied for user ...
```

So far so good. Let's throw some bad SQL at it instead:

```
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect(..., { PrintError => 0, RaiseError => 1 });
my $sth = $dbh->prepare('SLECT 1');
$sth->execute;
```

Outputs:

```
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SLECT 1' at line 1 at ...
```

Hmmm, not what I expected (there's no `In CORE::GLOBAL::die` message). According to the [docs](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.630/DBI.pm#RaiseError), when `RaiseError` is on,

> any method which results in an error will cause the DBI to effectively do a `die("$class $method failed: $DBI::errstr")`

I guess the key word is **effectively**, since I would expect an actual call to `die` to invoke my version of `CORE::GLOBAL::die`.

I can force all errors to `die` by setting `HandleError`:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect(..., { HandleError => sub { die shift; } })
```

But since `RaiseError` "can be used to force errors to raise exceptions rather than simply return error codes in the normal way," I don't understand why this is necessary. Why doesn't setting `RaiseError` always result in a call to `CORE::GLOBAL::die` on error? Isn't that the whole point of using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`die` is a Perl opcode (not a subroutine). It can't simply be called. Parts of DBI and DBD modules are written in C, so they wouldn't be able to use `die` (without calling back into Perl code as in your workaround).

You can still hook `$SIG{__DIE__}`, though. Like the article says, `GLOBAL::CORE::die` is for when "you really need to catch calls to `die`" (as opposed to catching exceptions being thrown).